# Proof of square of -1

Tags: real-analysis

With a field axiom concerning a structure of real numbers $\mathbb R$, like the Closure, Associative, Commutative, Distributive law and existence of the identity, inverse, etc. How to prove that $(-1)^2 = 1$? Should proofs of all formulas or statements in this axiom start with "there exists the number $1$, $0$" when we can't use any preceding theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(-1)^2-1=^{\color{red}{\vdash}}(-1)(-1+1)=0$. Then $(-1)^2=1$ by 
the uniqueness of the neutral element.

$\cdot$ in ${\color{red}{\vdash}}$ use distributive.

The existence of $1$ and $0$ are axioms too.

Comment: $(-1)^2 + 1 \neq 0$; you mean $(-1)^2+(-1)$.

Comment: And by associative I think you mean distributive.

Comment: Correct both. I'm sorry. I confused "distributive" when I went to translate.

Comment: I wonder what is ⊢. I've never seen this.

Comment: It is only a symbol for cross-reference. I basically used to inform you that in this passage you should use distributivity

Comment: At second point (-1)(-1 + "1"). Use of "1"  is possible when (-1)^2 is true, which we should proof. Can you explain this?

Comment: but the existence of identity $1$ is an axiom of real numbers.

Comment: $\left( -1 \right)^2 = -1$ ? Shouldnt it be $= 1$ ?

Comment: It may be little out of my first question, but I want to ask you. You use a=b=c, then a=c and a+k=c+k form. When we discuss about the field axiom which I said. Do we always assume that equal notation "=" has transitivity? or do the axiom already make that form possible?